# Change color of face of object in edit mode?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have searched but as of yet have not found an answer. Does anyone know how to color a face of an object while in *Edit Mode*?

Comment: With an assigned material or with vertex colors? By the tags it looks like with material - is this correct? Why is there UV tag though? Do you want to paint the uv unwrapped texture where the polygon is?

Comment: Assigned materials @Jerryno

Comment: @Jerryno I am trying to put multiple materials inside one object

Comment: Is this the answer you are looking for: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27631/assigning-material-to-every-second-face-via-python (for assigning faces to material), and this one http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/python-set-material-to-material-slot for multiple materials on one object?

Comment: nevermid i have found the solution

Comment: This guy explains it all. Skip to 5:38 to see
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3R0842q6jfE